# Using papaparse to parse a CSV file with Javascript in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse

I have a CSV file in the same directory as my React app that I am trying to read with Javascript. I am using Papaparse to parse the CSV file.

Here is my code:

```js
Papa.parse("./headlines.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results, file) {
    console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
  }
})
```

My issue is that when I try to parse the file, all that gets returned is the HTML code for the `index.html` file in my React app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to [PapaParser Docs](https://www.papaparse.com/docs), you need to pass in a js File Object or a CSV String.

```js
// file is a File object obtained from the DOM.
// config is a config object which contains a callback.
// Doesn't return anything. Results are provided asynchronously to a callback function.

Papa.parse(file, config)
```

**JS: Using Async/Await**

```js
const csv = await fetch('/headlines.csv').then( res => res.text() );

Papa.parse( csv, {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results, file) {
        console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
    }
});
```

**JS: Using Promises**

```js
fetch('/headlines.csv')
    .then( res => res.text() )
    .then( csv => {
        Papa.parse( csv, {
            download: true,
            complete: function(results, file) {
                console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file);
            }
        });
    });
```