# DOMException: error using PapaParse in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, papaparse, domexception

`import csvData from "./data/normal.csv";`

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(csvData);
      const data = await response.text();
      console.log({ data });
      parseCsv(data);
    })();
    parseCsv(csvData);
  }, []);
  const parseCsv = (dataCsv) => {
    Papa.parse(dataCsv, {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      worker: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function (results, file) {
        console.log(results, file);
      },
    });
  };
```

Error----------->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNigX.png)

Also tried this.....

```
const parseCsv = (csvData) => {
Papa.parse(csvData, {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  worker: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function (results, file) {
    console.log(results, file);
  },
});
```

};

according to the docs and some exaples online i should be getting a parsed csv file in JSON ormat in the results, but i am unable to debug this error.
have also tried directly passing the path in the fetch function, also tried passing the path directly in the Papa.parse(file,config). i am receiving  a sting obj with all the data in the console.log. idk, i am just floundering about now.

Comment: You're importing your csv but then trying to use that data as the URL for a fetch? That doesn't look right. If you're importing it you don't need to fetch the data too...

Comment: Originally i just passed the imported csv file in the papa. Parse fn like papa.parse(csvData,config). It did not work so.... I tried to mix a match watever i foumd online

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is that the **csvData** variable is not a valid URL. The **fetch()** function expects a **valid URL**, but **csvData** is a path to a file on your local machine. To fix this, you can use the **file:** protocol to specify the path to the file on your local machine.or you can use third party libiary [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-papaparse) to read the csv file

The image you sent me shows the error message Uncaught **DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL**. This error message means that the **XMLHttpRequest** object was unable to open the URL specified in the **csvData** variable. The most likely reason for this error is that the **csvData** variable is not a valid URL.

Comment: Hey, i tried the basic syntax also............... const parseCsv = (csvFilePath) => {
    Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      worker: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function (results, file) {
        console.log(results, file);
      },
    });

Comment: @aurogpt see these answers for reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752889/how-can-i-read-a-local-file-with-papa-parse)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76168994/22306426) found this.

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/papaparse-check-y6yrff?file=/src/App.js:394-401) ... bro if you could please help me here, my brain seems to have gone missing. it is working here on code-sandbox, but not on my system same code, still unable to understand the error, I mean I know the invalid URL part, but why, it should work ....shouldn't it